# Cassandra CQLSSTableWriter UDT type

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-types

Is it possible using CQLSSTableWriter to create SSTable for table with 'User Defined Type'? Is there some a workaround?

I read few articles like this 'http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated', but didn't find any suggestions for this.

Comment: please add some code

Answer (score 0):

Not yet.
JIRA issue is open though.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8006